# How to run bash script with getopt included in python?

Tags: python, bash, shell, getopt

I am running a script in the ubuntu terminal and it works fine.

```
./run_script2.sh -b ./exercises/13_caching.py
```

I want to run the same script in python os or subprocess but I am getting an error :

```
./run_script2.sh: line 36: getopt: command not found
```

On line 36 I have :

```
opts=`getopt -o f:b:ia:p:d:h --long no-status-srv --long status-port: -- "$@"`
```

How can I run this script as I run in the terminal using python?

Comment: Can you modify the script to run: `echo "$PATH"` and `type -P getopt` before that line, then run it normally and in Python and see how they differ? We also need a [MCVE] showing how you're running them in Python. Odds are running them from the shell is pulling in some `PATH` modifications from your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or the like which Python doesn't have (though Python *itself* should inherit those same modification if run in a shell); the first step to fixing it is figuring out how the two environments differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopt` is not in your `PATH` and then not found.

Try:

```
opts=$(/usr/bin/getopt -o f:b:ia:p:d:h --long no-status-srv --long status-port: -- "$@")
```

assuming `/usr/bin/` is where `getopt` is located.

Comment: Getopt is working fine now but getting error : "python3: can't open file '$prog/install/lib/python3.6/site-packages/p4testutils/bf_switchd_dev_status.py' [Errno 2] No such file or directory." The same script is working fine in shell but getting error while running on python subprocess. What may be the issue?

Comment: `prog` might be unset or it's running as a different user that has no permission on that file.